# React Native error [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: term]

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

After creating custom hook useResutls.js i am getting below error in my react-native app.

**[ReferenceError: Can't find variable: term]**

I am fetching data from yelp api.

**Below is my code of yelp.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: ' https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer oJE_h1-idlATvhGffz5O-y8pfvLkmm3e2KlORp0A2lXL51K49PVScyccnlDH0nIa_josBxOqQoGnobJudRnQOn9eBsebxG_shV1QvkSmt-qYh-W2rPDbi7YmnxpzY3Yx'
    }
})
```

**useResults hook file useResults.js code is below**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import yelp from '../api/yelp';

export default () => {

const [results, setResults] = useState([])
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')

const searchApi = async () => {
  try {
  const response = await yelp.get('/search', {
    params: {
      limit:50,
      term,
      location: 'san jose'
    } 
  })
  console.log(term)
  setResults(response.data.businesses)
} catch (err) {
  //setErrorMessage('Something Went Wrong')
  console.log(err)
}
};

useEffect(() => {
    searchApi('pizza')
  },[]);

return [searchApi, results, errorMessage]

}
```

**Below is my SearchScreen.js code**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar'
import useResults from '../hooks/useResults'


const SearchScreen = (searchTerm) => {

const [term, setTerm] = useState('')
const [searchApi, results, errorMessage] = useResults();


  return (
    <View>
        <SearchBar 
        term={term} 
        onTermChange={setTerm}
          
        onTermSubmit={()=> searchApi(term)}
        />
        {errorMessage ? <Text>{errorMessage}</Text> : null}
        <Text >We have found {results.length} results</Text>
        
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default SearchScreen
```

**Below is code of App.js file**

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack'
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import SearchScreen from './src/screens/SearchScreen'

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
Search: SearchScreen

}, 
{
  intialRouteName: 'Search',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    title: 'Business Search'
  }
}
)

export default createAppContainer(navigator)
```

**Below is SearchBar.js component file code.**

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet,TextInput} from 'react-native'
import {Feather} from '@expo/vector-icons'


const SearchBar = ({term, onTermChange,onTermSubmit}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.background}>
        <Feather name="search" size={30} style={styles.iconStyle}/>
        <TextInput 
        autoCapitalize='none'
        autoCorrect={false}
        placeholder="Search" style={styles.inputStyle}
        value={term}
        onChangeText={onTermChange}
        onEndEditing={onTermSubmit}
        />
        
    </View>
  )
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        height:50,
        borderRadius:5,
        marginHorizontal:15,
        flexDirection:'row', 
        alignItems:'center'   
    },
    inputStyle:{
        flex:1,
        fontSize:18,
        paddingLeft:20
    },
    iconStyle:{
        fontSize:35,
        alignSelf:'center',
        paddingLeft:10
        
    }
});


export default SearchBar
```

Comment: Where are you declare your `term` in `searchApi()` in **useResults.js**?

Comment: Thanks brother for the hint. I have fixed it in in useResutls.js by adding searchTerm argument and passed it to term: searchTerm and its working fine now.

const searchApi = async searchTerm => {